# Distortion in Manual Reconstruction of Function using Numpy rfft2

Tags: numpy, fft

I am using numpy's rfft2 to take the Fourier transform of a function f(x,y). I then want to manually extract the coefficients and reconstruct the function. The purpose of doing this is to see how early I can truncate the series. The probelm is that I am encountering an odd distortion effect that is even appearing even for very simple functions. I have attached the code below that demonstrates this issue with a simple function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
a = 3.66
b = 1.75
Nx = 256  # Number of sample points in x
Ny = 256  # Number of sample points in y
truncation = 32 # Ensure this is less than the Nyquist frequency: Ny//2 + 1

# Create a grid of points in the domain
x = np.linspace(-a, a, Nx)
y = np.linspace(-b, b, Ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Evaluate the function on the grid
F = np.cos(X) * np.cos(Y)

# Apply FFT
F_fft = np.fft.rfft2(F)

# Automatic reconstruction using irfft2 (for comparison)
F_auto_reconstructed = np.fft.irfft2(F_fft, s=(Nx, Ny))

# Manual Reconstruction
F_reconstructed = np.zeros_like(F, dtype=np.complex128)
for kx in range(truncation):
    for ky in range(truncation): 
        exp = np.exp(2j * np.pi * (kx * np.arange(Nx)[:, None] / Nx + ky * np.arange(Ny)[None, :] / Ny))
        F_reconstructed += F_fft[kx, ky] * exp

F_reconstructed /= (Nx * Ny)

# Plotting for comparison
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(18, 6))
axes[0].imshow(F, extent=[-a, a, -b, b], cmap='viridis')
axes[0].set_title('Original F')
axes[1].imshow(F_auto_reconstructed, extent=[-a, a, -b, b], cmap='viridis')
axes[1].set_title('Automatically Reconstructed F')
axes[2].imshow(np.real(F_reconstructed), extent=[-a, a, -b, b], cmap='viridis')
axes[2].set_title('Manually Reconstructed F')

plt.show()
```

I am fairly certain that the issue is not the function itself, since the irfft2 is able to reconstruct the function with no issue. I am also fairly certain that the resolution and the size of my truncation are not issues either as the distortion persists across various resolution and truncation pairings. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're applying the inverse transform to only some frequencies, and not selecting the frequency pairs that together form a real-valued inverse. In 1D, if you use frequency k, you also need to use frequency N-k. They're a pair. But `rfft` doesn't return the frequencies above `N//2`, you need to compute those. The FFT for the frequency N-k is the complex conjugate of the one for k. In 2D these relationships are more complex, as the function performs a RFFT on the last dimension, and then a normal FFT on the remaining dimensions. Why don't you do your experiment in 1D, to keep it simple?

Comment: Excellent advice thank you very much, problem solved. I will post the corrected code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the advice from Cris Luengo the the correction was quick to make. The corrected code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
a = 3.66
b = 1.75
Nx = 256  # Number of sample points in x
Ny = 256  # Number of sample points in y
truncation = 16 # Ensure this is less than the Nyquist frequency: Ny//2 + 1

# Create a grid of points in the domain
x = np.linspace(-a, a, Nx)
y = np.linspace(-b, b, Ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Evaluate the function on the grid
F = np.cos(X) * np.cos(Y)

# Apply FFT
F_fft = np.fft.rfft2(F)

# Automatic reconstruction using irfft2 (for comparison)
F_auto_reconstructed = np.fft.irfft2(F_fft, s=(Nx, Ny))

# Manual Reconstruction
F_reconstructed = np.zeros_like(F, dtype=np.complex128)
for kx in range(-truncation, truncation):
    for ky in range(truncation):  # Keeping ky positive as rfft2's last axis is half-sized
        # Calculate the correct indices for kx
        kx_index = kx if kx >= 0 else Nx + kx
        # Calculate exponential terms for each dimension
        exp_x = np.exp(2j * np.pi * kx * np.arange(Nx)[:, None] / Nx)
        exp_y = np.exp(2j * np.pi * ky * np.arange(Ny)[None, :] / Ny)
        # Apply the FFT coefficient to the exponential terms
        # Note: For negative kx, we need to use the complex conjugate of the positive counterpart
        # This is inherently handled for the 'y' dimension by the nature of the real-to-complex FFT
        F_reconstructed += F_fft[kx_index, ky] * exp_x * exp_y

F_reconstructed /= (Nx * Ny)

# Plotting for comparison
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(18, 6))
axes[0].imshow(F, extent=[-a, a, -b, b], cmap='viridis')
axes[0].set_title('Original F')
axes[1].imshow(F_auto_reconstructed, extent=[-a, a, -b, b], cmap='viridis')
axes[1].set_title('Automatically Reconstructed F')
axes[2].imshow(np.real(F_reconstructed), extent=[-a, a, -b, b], cmap='viridis')
axes[2].set_title('Manually Reconstructed F')

plt.show()
```